# How does one correctly stop a substrate node

Tags: substrate

The second bullet point in the [create-your-first-substrate-chain tutorial](https://substrate.dev/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/interact#starting-your-node) alludes to

> properly terminate your node

How does one properly terminate a substrate node in order to "save all active data for the node"?

I reckon ctrl + c will stop it, but the tutorial suggests there might be a better way without elaborating.

Comment: It means nothing further than stopping your node. It is true that the way it is expressed makes you think that can be a way that is better than the rest, but it is not the case.
The context just refer to stopping it from running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ctrl + c` is the proper way to stop your running Substrate node.